# Not able to run Http(s) script recorder in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

For recording scenarios using JMeter, after clicking the start button in the Http(S) script recorder getting an error message.[image: Error message]

and getting log as

```
2015/10/05 18:10:35 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui 
2015/10/05 18:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui 
2015/10/05 18:10:37 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool' 
2015/10/05 18:10:37 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file D:\jmeter\apache-jmete-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2015/10/05 18:10:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2015/10/05 18:10:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2015/10/05 18:10:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2015/10/05 18:10:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2015/10/05 18:11:01 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not open/read key store D:\jmeter\apache-jmete-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks (The system cannot find the file specified) 
2015/10/05 18:11:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Creating Proxy CA in D:\jmeter\apache-jmete-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2015/10/05 18:11:02 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException:   >> Illegal option:  -ext
Try keytool -help <<
Command failed, code: 1
'keytool -genkeypair -alias :root_ca: -dname "CN=_ DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username: Admin, C=IN" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted} -keypass {redacted} -validity 7 -ext bc:c'
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:170)
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateProxyCA(KeyToolUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initDynamicKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1356)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:465)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:507)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.actionPerformed(ProxyControlGui.java:381)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to upgrade your JDK (or JRE) to the latest one.

If you're in position to choose I would recommend [64-bit Oracle JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Since version 2.10 JMeter explicitly relies on Java 7 specific "keytool" application options to generate a self-signed certificate for recording HTTPS traffic.

See

- [TestRecording210](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210) wiki page for detailed explanation

and

- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide for some more troubleshooting tips.